# How to reference a csv file within vb.net program files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have the file located within my project (visualstudio2013\projects\Proj4\Proj4\file.csv) and I want to reference it in my code without having to go from the root C drive up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know it's got to be something simple but I can't seem to find it.

Not sure why I can't find this answer in my searching on Google..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A csv file is a text file. There are several ways to read a text file with .Net. You can specify the filename and path in full - See for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't want to go from the root up. This program will be run on other systems but I'm not publishing it either. I just want to reference it from within the program. Does it have to be in the debug?

Comment: Think I may have figured it out... System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\file.csv"). Can someone verify this for me that this is the correct way to do this?

Comment: is the CSV something static your app uses? Depending on what you will do with this, a better way is to use the `Users` folders

Comment: Yes it is static but this program isn't something where I need it to be that "commercial grade". It is for a programming class. We are making a database program and instead of hard coding default values into the tables I wanted to bring in a csv file. Seemed to make more sense to me.

Comment: database values belong in the database, not csv

Comment: Sigh... I realize this. They are default values that we are given to put in the database. But as I stated above, I am trying to put them in without hard coding. We are creating the database straight from code. Not a pre-existing database.